# Declaration of a function in c programming

Tags: c, function, declaration

If a function(say a()) prototype is declared inside a function(say main()) does it mean that it cannot be used in functions other that main() function?

Answer (score 3):

No that does not mean that. If the other functions declare it too, then the function can be used by those other functions too.

```
int main(void) {
  void f(void); 
  f();
}

void g(void) {
  void f(void);
  f();
}
```

In this example, `main` declared function `f` locally and called it. But `g` does that same thing too. Both declarations refer to the same function.

Comment: Well, you may as well declare it at outer unit scope if you are going to do that!

Comment: I mean, what you say is correct, but I can't help feeling it's not quite what the question was driving at, but then again, I could be wrong....

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct. That is true for all declarations within a particular scope. They are only available within the defining scope.

Of course, you can declare the same function in another scope, but I don't think that's what you meant.

Answer (score -1):

In general things that you are able to declare inside a function (e.g. variables) are only in use for that function.

Comment: I think you are confused between declarations and definitions.